# Java Regex causes hung thread

Tags: java, regex, hung

Pattern:

```
"(([^",\n  ]*[,\n  ])*([^",\n  ]*"{2})*)*[^",\n  ]*"[  ]*,[  ]*|[^",\n]*[  ]*,[  ]*|"(([^",\n  ]*[,\n  ])*([^",\n  ]*"{2})*)*[^",\n  ]*"[  ]*|[^",\n]*[  ]*
```

This Regex is for parsing CSV file. But when it goes into Pattern.matcher, I encounter a hung thread exception. Appreciate it if someone can help fine tune this pattern.

```
[7/1/13 16:45:26:745 GMT+08:00] 00000029 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "MessageListenerThreadPool : 0" (00000035) has been active for 691836 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4233)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4752)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4689)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4733)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4665)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4754)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4689)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4742)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4665)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BitClass.match(Pattern.java:2912)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4278)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4233)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4752)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4689)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4606)
```

Comment: we won't be able to fine tune your regex unless you show us the exact input and output required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

The problem appears to be the shear amount of back tracking being done to accomplish the match.

If your CSV is well formed you could use a more simple regex to parse each line. Note this will only separate the quote-comma and comma delimited values from a string, so you'd need to pass each line through the .matcher with this regex and iterate over each of the matches.

regex:  `(?:^|,)"?((?<=")[^"]*|[^,"]*)"?(?=,|$)`

[image]

## Java Code Example:

Live example: http://ideone.com/NBmzrk

**Sample Text**

```
"root",test1,1111,"22,22",,fdsa
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?:^|,)\"?((?<=\")[^\"]*|[^,\"]*)\"?(?=,|$)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Capture Group 1**

```
[0] => root
[1] => test1
[2] => 1111
[3] => 22,22
[4] => 
[5] => fdsa
```

Comment: I've changed to use opencsv to parse CSV file. Thanks for your suggestion all the same.